# How to structure "user friends" collections in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, data-structures, nosql

I have a questions about what is the best way to structure "user connections" system in MongoDB, like Linkedin works.
I have the next options but I don't know what is the best way in the future, with millions rows in collections.

- Option 1: Two collections, **user** and **user-connect** relation
  *one-to-one* in **user-connect** with this fields: `user_one`, `user_two`,
  `status` ("pending", "accepted", "rejected", "bloecked"). When user
  request connect to another user, I need just insert a new document in
  user-connect collection, but I have a problem: I need to follow all
  queries to get "contacts" of a user in two fields, `user_one` and
  `user_two` because just exists one insert between both.
- Option 2: The same structure that option 1 but instead of 1 insert, 2
  inserts: The first one will be the request, just a document with
  status pending, and the second one will be when this connection is
  accepted. Two documents, two insert but when I need to query for user
  contacts, just need to get information in one field: `user_one`
- Option 3: *one-to-many* structure, **user-connect** will has an `user_one`
  field and contacts field, array of user ids, but reading another
  forums, this not is recommended because a lot of "match" system in the
  future.

Comment: Could you possibly add some very simple schema and 2-3 inserts for option 1 and 2? Pointless to do a comparison if we incorrectly read your model.

Comment: For example: David wants to connect with Michael, David put on "Connect" button in the website (like a linkedin). With Option 1 user-connection collection will has just one insert,  user_one is David and user_two is Michael. Michael is pending to approve the request. When michael approve it, this document will change his status to "approve". but if michael needs to get his contacts, the query has two fields to search, user_one and user_two. With option 2 it won't happens because exists two documents: one for David and one for Michael. I hope u understand